# JS, Socket.io, Phaser3, Object Not Being Created

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, callback, phaser-framework

I'm a JS, phaser3 and Socket.io newbie and I really want to learn.

Code Context:

- Phaser3
- Socket.io
- Loading state of game room before socket connects
- Generating the NPC's and players
- fails when there's an attempt to access NPC's (mass) sprite in the same callback it was created

Issue:

- Cannot access the sprite property, and in general seems like the object wasn't created in the first place

I have the socket listening in Phaser3's "create()" function for "universeState" after it has connected to the socket server. index.js:

```
this.socket.on('universeState',(universe)=>
    {
        console.log(`mass? ${JSON.stringify(universe.sys.mass[1].id)}`)
        for(let i = 0;i < universe.sys.mass.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(universe.sys.mass[i].id,universe.sys.mass[i].x,universe.sys.mass[i].y,universe.sys.mass[i].asset);
            this.utils.genMass(universe.sys.mass[i].id,universe.sys.mass[i].x,universe.sys.mass[i].y,universe.sys.mass[i].asset);
            console.log(`check: 3 ${JSON.stringify(this.state.state.mass)}`);
            this.state.state.mass[universe.sys.mass[i].id].sprite.setScale(0.5,0.5); //issue here
            console.log('check: 4');

            this.physics.add.collider(this.state.state.mass[universe.sys.mass[i].id].sprite, this.state.state.playerMass[this.state.id].sprite, function(mass, player) {
                mass.destroy();
                player.setScale(player.scaleX + 0.03);
                let camera = this.cameras.main;
                camera.zoomTo(camera.zoom * 0.975);
            }, null, this);
        }
```

function used to create the "mass" in utils.js:

```
genMass(id,x,y,tex)
{
    console.log(`creating sprite with operands: ${id},${x},${y},${tex}`);
    let sprite = this.scene.physics.add.sprite(50,50,tex)//needs to be a physics object
    if(id.substring(0,5)=='mass:')
    {
        console.log(`is equal`)
    }
    id.substring(0,4)=='mass:'?
    this.scene.state.state.mass[id] = {id:id,sprite:sprite,x:x,y:y}:
    this.scene.state.state.playerMass[id] = {id:id,sprite:sprite,x:x,y:y}; //generate an extra parameter argument for quantified mass
    console.log('check: 0');
    id.substring(0,4)=='mass:'?
    this.scene.physics.world.enable(this.scene.state.state.mass[id].sprite):
    this.scene.physics.world.enable(this.scene.state.state.playerMass[id].sprite); 
    console.log('check: 1');
    id.substring(0,4)=='mass:'?
    this.scene.state.state.mass[id].sprite.body.collideWorldBounds = true:
    this.scene.state.state.playerMass[id].sprite.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    console.log('check: 2');

}
```

everything first appears wrong in the first code snippet where it's commented "issue here". Since I am using webpack, the bundled files are little help. console:

```
Player ID returned:null
bundle.min.js:1 connected to game
bundle.min.js:1 mass? "mass:3961482"
bundle.min.js:1 mass:7107097 19134 14999 arc_purple
bundle.min.js:1 creating sprite with operands: mass:7107097,19134,14999,arc_purple
bundle.min.js:1 is equal
bundle.min.js:1 check: 0
bundle.min.js:1 check: 1
bundle.min.js:1 check: 2
bundle.min.js:1 check: 3 {}
bundle.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sprite')
    at Q.<anonymous> (bundle.min.js:1:978636)
    at Q.i.emit (bundle.min.js:1:40837)
    at Q.emitEvent (bundle.min.js:1:969227)
    at Q.onevent (bundle.min.js:1:969030)
    at Q.onpacket (bundle.min.js:1:968708)
    at et.i.emit (bundle.min.js:1:40837)
    at et.ondecoded (bundle.min.js:1:973286)
    at q.i.emit (bundle.min.js:1:40837)
    at q.add (bundle.min.js:1:964368)
    at et.ondata (bundle.min.js:1:973261)
```

Questions:

Why is the object I created empty when logging it? How can I successfully create the object and access it?

Notes:

I have suspicions that it's some sort of callback behavior that you can't initialize something and access it in the same callback. I'm relatively new and I want to learn thanks.

Comment: First... substring doesn't cover the colon... make sure the range is 0-5 (the second argument for whatever reason doesn't start at 0 blame Brendan Eich). Tell me where that takes you....

Comment: I can say now without conjecture, that you've fixed that bug and now you're onto another. In your code, we know mass exists, so that might be the playerMass sprite you're trying to access.... did you create an object for the player??

Comment: btw.: in your code your once checking  `id.substring(0,4)=='mass:'` , this can never be true, because `'mass:'` has a length of `5`, so only the `else` part will be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things we spoke in comment section.

1. Your substring needed to include the colon to pass the test for creating an object of type mass.
2. Object for playerMass was not created.

You're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you cant access the property is "easy", it's because the `this.state.state.mass` object is empty.

since te output:

```
...
bundle.min.js:1 check: 3 {}
bundle.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sprite')
```

and the code lines:

```
console.log(`check: 3 ${JSON.stringify(this.state.state.mass)}`);
```

So if `this.state.state.mass` is an empty `object`/ `{}`, so there is no proptery `universe.sys.mass[i].id` in that `object`.

So `this.state.state.mass[universe.sys.mass[i].id]` is `undefined`, and undefined has no property `sprite`, and this is the error message.

Why this is `undefined` is hard to tell *without more code*, but with the *current shared* code, I would have to guess: In the socket function you are using `this.state.state.mass` and in the `genMass` function you are using `this.scene.state.state.mass`, this could  be the cause, since this are probably different objects.

**Update:**
After re-reading the code, you should check the part of your code that compares the `substring` with `'mass:'`, since here only the second part of the **if/else** block will be executed, because `id.substring(0,4)` has a string length of 4 and `'mass:'` has a string length of 5 so these will **never** match.

> btw.: to use the `ternary operator` `?:` instead of `if`/`else` is not the best option, and makes the code less readable.

```
    id.substring(0,4)=='mass:'?
        this.scene.state.state.mass[id] = {id:id,sprite:sprite,x:x,y:y}:
        this.scene.state.state.playerMass[id] = {id:id,sprite:sprite,x:x,y:y}; //generate an extra parameter argument for quantified mass
    console.log('check: 0');
    id.substring(0,4)=='mass:'?
        this.scene.physics.world.enable(this.scene.state.state.mass[id].sprite):
        this.scene.physics.world.enable(this.scene.state.state.playerMass[id].sprite); 
    console.log('check: 1');
    id.substring(0,4)=='mass:'?
        this.scene.state.state.mass[id].sprite.body.collideWorldBounds = true:
        this.scene.state.state.playerMass[id].sprite.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    console.log('check: 2');
```

this is more readable:

```
    if(id.substring(0,4)=='mass:'){
        this.scene.state.state.mass[id] = {id:id,sprite:sprite,x:x,y:y};
        this.scene.physics.world.enable(this.scene.state.state.mass[id].sprite);
        this.scene.state.state.mass[id].sprite.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    } else {
        this.scene.state.state.playerMass[id] = {id:id,sprite:sprite,x:x,y:y};
        this.scene.physics.world.enable(this.scene.state.state.playerMass[id].sprite);
        this.scene.state.state.playerMass[id].sprite.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
    }
```

... or this, this is probably even clearer:

```
    let mass = {id:id,sprite:sprite,x:x,y:y};
    this.scene.physics.world.enable(sprite);
    sprite.body.collideWorldBounds = true;

    if(id.substring(0,4)=='mass:'){
        this.scene.state.state.mass[id] = mass;
    } else {
        this.scene.state.state.playerMass[id] = mass;
    }
```

Comment: hi thanks for your response. The socket code is located in the index file, and the genMass is located in a class that has access to the scene (index.js). Unless I'm ignorant to something, my object should be created. utils(this) : this.scene.state.state = index.js : this.state.state

Comment: the `genMass` function, where is it located? is it part of the `scene`, or better asked, what is the `this` of the `genMass` pointing to? because `scene`  has also a `scene`property. https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scene.html#scene__anchor